# Los Bootstrap Modals no se pueden visualizar

Tags: php, html5, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo un index.php, con el cual a través de un div cargo otros paginas.php, la navegacion que pose el menú esta hecha con ajax para que el contenido se modifique sin tener que recargar el toda la pagina. Cuando cargo las otras paginas todo el contenido se visualiza con normalidad excepto los Modals de Bootstrap se visualizan de forma rapida y desaparecen no se que es lo que esto haciendo mal.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">    
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Document</title> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Este es la pagina principal</h1>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="crud();">CRUD</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Cargar contenido yo soy el index</h3>
 <div id="contenedor">
  
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
```

Este es todo el contenido del index.php, como pueden notar en unos de los elementos a se encuentra la funcion ajax que me permite seleccionar la pagina que quiero mostrar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar le click a esa opcion, se ejecuta este codigo.

```js
function crud(){
 $.ajax({
  url : "php/crud.php",//valor obligatorio para solicitar el doc que se quiere cargar
  dataType : "text",
  success : function(data) {
   $("#contenedor").html(data);//Id del contenedor para mostrar el archivo
  }
 });
}
```

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h6>Hola desde el crud.php</h6>
<div id="contenedor" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Demo: PHP and MySQL CRUD Operations using Jquery</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Add New Record</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>Records:</h3>

            <div class="records_content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Content Section -->


<!-- Bootstrap Modals -->
<!-- Modal - Add New Record/User -->
<div class="modal fade" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Record</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord()">Add Record</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- // Modal -->

<!-- Modal - Update User details -->
<div class="modal fade" id="update_user_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_first_name">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_last_name">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateUserDetails()" >Save Changes</button>
                <input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_id">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Así que no logro descubrir lo que estoy haciendo mal. ese es todo el codigo tal vez me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Si te entendí bien, el modal abre pero se cierra de manera automática al instante?

Comment: si se abre cuando presiono el botón, pero se abre muy rápido y desaparece sin poder mantener se en la pantalla y no me logro explicar porque.

Comment: que versión de boostrap y jquery estas usando?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.5 y jQuery v1.11.3

Comment: Es estaño, estoy ejecutando tu código https://jsfiddle.net/y6umyfsp/2/, y corre sin problema, lo que me hace pensar que puede que tengas un js que este haciendo conflicto. Prueba agregando **data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" ** a tu botón que llama el modal y me cuentas.

Comment: ..si osea por si solo el codigo de el CRUD, funciona bien, pero uniendo la navegación de ajax es donde me da problemas, hay un archivo llamado funciones.js en el cual esta la función que ejecuta el crud.php

Comment: muchas gracias problema solventado todo esta en como llama los js y los css gracias